# Jetty SSL configuration as a client service

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, jetty, esb

I need to setup a secure connection to an ESB that requires my Jetty to use a .crt certificate, and I don't know where to start or how to do it, only using the .XML and other config files that are on my Jetty AppServer.

Basically the architecture is the following.

```
----------------
| http server  |
----------------
      |  |
----------------
|    jetty     |
----------------
     |ssl|
     |com|
     \   /
      \ /
----------------
|     esb      |
----------------
```

I through Jetty's documentation, and it is all about having SSL certificates when Jetty is acting as a server; not as a client which is my case, so I need help sorting out that...

Thanks!

Comment: Any answer to this heavily depends on knowing what your client is.  what library? what version of that library? what version of Java?

Comment: While @JoakimErdfelt is correct regarding specifics if we assume you are using Jetty's HTTPClient the general idea here is that you want to create a Java key store that contains the certificate that's stored in the .crt file and then configure a Jetty SSLContextFactory object using that keystore and then pass that SSLContextFactory to the HTTPClient's constructor.